# Updating one column with a value of another if nil?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

There is a column within my car table called 'manufacture_date' and another column called 'registration_date'. When a user updates a record via the update action in the controller. Manufacture date can currently be left nil. However, if it is nil I want the value of the registration_date(which cannot be left nil) to be copied into the manufacture date. I'm really not to sure how to accomplish this. Note: I do not want to rescue or allow a nil value. I need it if nil, to contain the same date as the registration_date.

Manufacturer date code ran when user updates the record in a form.

```
  new_manufacture_date = Date.parse(params[:car][:manufacture_date])
```

Comment: that can be achieved with an `after_commit` callback
in your model `after_save :update_manufacture_date` then create a method with that name to update the column
https://api.rubyonrails.org/v7.0.4/classes/ActiveRecord/Transactions/ClassMethods.html#method-i-after_commit

Comment: My confusion comes with what the code would be within the method that would take the registration_date and copy it into the manufacture_date.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way would be a `before_validation` callback in your model like this:

```
before_validation :set_manufacture_date_fallback

private

def set_manufacture_date_fallback
  self.manufacture_date ||= registration_date
end
```

Which would assign the value of `registration_date` to `manufacture_date` when `manufacture_date` is not set yet right before validating and saving the record into the database.

Comment: Yes this works exactly how I wanted it to. Thank you!